# How many ports HAProxy machine opens

Tags: reverse-proxy, haproxy, port, tcp

I have below port range configured

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
32768 61000
```

So, 28232 will be no.of available ports

I have HAProxy Configured to take 5000 connection with 2 processor
So, HAProxy will take 10,000 concurrent connections

sample haproxy.conf file

```
frontend main
bind *:80
acl is_app_user -i ^/myApp/app/.*/user.*
acl is_app_members path_reg -i ^/myApp/.*

use_backend user if is_app_user
use_backend member if is_app_members

backend user
   server app1 127.0.0.1:8081

backend member
   server app2 member.app.com:443 ssl verify none check
```

How many Ports that machine running HAProxy opens?

28232 x 2 = 56,464. Since, backend is different IP address or irrespective of backend server, source port always remains at 28,232?

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify: Your issue is one of source port exhaustion when establishing connections to your respective backends, correct?

A workaround might be to assign more IP addresses to the network interface(s) of the HAProxy and assign the same backend server multiple times using the `source` directive in your backend server definitions:

```
backend foo
    server appsrv1-1 member.app.com:443 source 10.0.0.10 ssl verify none check 
    server appsrv1-2 member.app.com:443 source 10.0.0.11 ssl verify none check 
    server appsrv1-3 member.app.com:443 source 10.0.0.12 ssl verify none check 
    ...
```

This should give you a bunch more ports to use.

Comment: Yes, my issue with source port exhaustion. So, no.of ports availability is based on the source IP not how many different backend servers (different IP address) that we have?

Comment: I frankly don't know what happens if you manage to open several tens of thousands of connections to a single backend IP/port - I suspect you would see performance degradation long before that with most kinds of web applications - but at least this should be a valid way to exceed your configured number of source ports.